# keep getting invalid column name bookings when that is my table name not my column name

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        abcfiles.dbo.diary.BOOKNO,
        abcfiles.dbo.BOOKINGS.PARTY,
        abcfiles.dbo.BOOKINGS.DEPART,
        abcfiles.dbo.BOOKINGS.DEP7,
        abcfiles.dbo.BOOKINGS.BOOKED,
        abcfiles.dbo.BOOKINGS.BOOK7,
        abcfiles.dbo.BOOKINGS.APRICE,
        abcfiles.dbo.BOOKINGS.PAID,
        abcfiles.dbo.DIARY.ADDED,
        abcfiles.dbo.DIARY.ADDED7,
        abcfiles.dbo.DIARY.TEXT,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY abcfiles.dbo.BOOKINGS.BOOKNO ORDER BY abcfiles.dbo.diary.ADDED DESC) AS RowNum
    FROM
        abcfiles.dbo.BOOKINGS
    INNER JOIN abcfiles.dbo.DIARY ON abcfiles.dbo.BOOKINGS.BOOKNO = abcfiles.dbo.DIARY.BOOKNO
    WHERE
    (
        abcfiles.dbo.BOOKINGS.PAID IS NULL
    ) OR
    (
        abcfiles.dbo.BOOKINGS.PAID = 0
    )
) t     
WHERE
    t.RowNum = 1 
END
```

The reason that I keep writing abcfiles is because I need my stored procedure stored in a different database.

Comment: I would suggest that you use a table alias. Also, it looks like this is part of some other code (the END statement isn't part of a SELECT). Are you sure that the error isn't on another line of the code?

Comment: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure unpaidbookings, Line 15
The multi-part identifier "dbo.BOOKINGS.BOOKNO" could not be bound.

Comment: That's not saying that BOOKINGS is a column... are you sure that BOOKNO exists as a column in the table?

Comment: The abcfiles database could be set to be case sensitive, in which case it could all be the right names, but wrong casing to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use aliases (`t` was already an alias).

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
        b.BOOKNO, b.PARTY, b.DEPART, b.DEP7, b.BOOKED, b.BOOK7, b.APRICE, b.PAID,
        d.ADDED, d.ADDED7, d.TEXT,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY b.BOOKNO ORDER BY d.ADDED DESC) AS RowNum      
     FROM abcfiles.dbo.BOOKINGS as b
    INNER JOIN abcfiles.dbo.DIARY as d ON b.BOOKNO = d.BOOKNO
    WHERE (b.PAID IS NULL)
       OR (b.PAID = 0)) t     
WHERE t.RowNum = 1
```

The `as` keyword is optional.

Happy SQL'ing.